# Long landscaped table

Tags: longtable, tabularx, landscape

I've created a table with http://www.tablesgenerator.com/ and wrapped it with

```
\afterpage{
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtabu}{X}
```

to rotate the table and fit it to as many pages it needs.

My code looks like the following:

```
\afterpage{
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtabu}{X}
\begin{tabularx}{0.5\textheight}{X|l}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
% Header
% Content
\end{tabular}
\end{tabularx}
\end{longtabu}
\end{landscape}
}
```

The problem is: it's not being rotated and it's overflowing the page space. What should I do?

EDIT

I forgot to mention. The first lines of my document are:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,openany]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\input{TesePack}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\thispagestyle{empty}

\input{Capa}

\cleardoublepage

\pagebreak
% Table of Contents
% ---------------------------------------------------------------
\tableofcontents
% ---------------------------------------------------------------

\mainmatter
\cleardoublepage
```

EDIT

Ok, maybe it's wasn't clear enough.
The code it's here:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,openany]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\input{TesePack}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\thispagestyle{empty}

\input{Capa}

\cleardoublepage

\pagebreak
% Table of Contents
% ---------------------------------------------------------------
     \tableofcontents
% ---------------------------------------------------------------

\mainmatter
\cleardoublepage

% ---------------------------------------------------------------
% Chapter 1 - Descrição do estudo de caso
% ---------------------------------------------------------------
\chapter{Descrição do estudo de caso}
\label{descricao}
\input{descricao}


\end{document}
```

And the "descricao" file, which my table is included, it's here:

```
\afterpage{
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtabu}{X}
\begin{tabularx}{0.5\textheight}{X|l}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Atividade de Suporte}}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Ligação com a cadeia de fornecedores (insumos)}}} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{Atividades Primárias}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Ligação com a cadeia de distribuidores}}} \\ \cline{3-7}
                                                                    &                                                                                                & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\textbf{Logística Interna}}                                                                                             & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\textbf{Operações}}                                & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\textbf{Logística Externa}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\textbf{Marketing e Vendas}}        & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Serviços}}                                                    &                                                                                        \\ \hline
\textbf{Aquisição}                                                  & Dados das Agências de Saúde                                                                    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}<span style="line-height: 1.5em;">Equipe</span>\\ <span style="line-height: 1.5em;">Hardware</span>\end{tabular} & Subentende-se a utilização de um software de gerenciamento do workflow & Não se aplica                                   & Não se aplica                                           & Realização de parcerias com Agências Internacionais de Saúde                               & Não se aplica                                                                          \\ \hline
\textbf{Tecnologia e Desenvolvimento}                               & Agrega valor com os dados fornecidos das empresas parceiras                                    & Transferência de tecnologia agregando valor ao conhecimento                                                                                 & Não se aplica                                                          & Não se aplica, pois o produto próprio           & Não se aplica, pois o projeto está no inicio            & Melhorar o algoritmo para dar mais precisão as previsões                                   & Permitir um acesso mais rápido a informação sobre as previsões                         \\ \hline
\textbf{Administração de Recursos Humanos}                          & Estabelecer parcerias com agências de saúde                                                    & Recrutamento de profissionais qualificados                                                                                                  & Manter atualização constante de treinamento especializado              & Não se aplica                                   & Não se aplica                                           & Tornar transparente as formas de acesso dos clientes à empresa para a correção do problema & Não se aplica                                                                          \\ \hline
\textbf{Sistemas de Administração}                                  & Garantir a privacidade dos usuários                                                            & Controle dos dados fornecidos pelas Agências de Saúde                                                                                       & Acompanhamento dos dados atualizados sobre gripe no mundo              & Não se aplica                                   & Acompanhamento de notícias relacionadas ao produto para & Apresentação dos resuldados através do site próprio                                        & Não se aplica                                                                          \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{tabularx}
\end{longtabu}
\end{landscape}
}
```

As I told in the comments section, I'm new to Latex, so I don't really know what I'm doing. I want to create a landscaped table and it's a long one. I've created the code with tablesgenerator.com, as I told you, and I though wrapping it around \begin{landscape} would rotate it. But it doesn't and I don't know why

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: It is far from clear what output you are trying to get. You have a tabular inside a tabularx inside a longtabu, which seems like 2 table environments too many:-) longtabu will break over a page but tabularx and tabular will not, so essentially you just have the inner tabular, the tabularx and longtabu can not do anything useful

Comment: Please don't post multiple unconnected fragments, post a single (smal) complete document that shows the problem

Comment: I'm new to Latex, so I don't really know what I'm doing. I want to create a landscaped table and it's a long one. I've created the code with http://www.tablesgenerator.com/, as I told you, and I though wrapping it around \begin{landscape} would rotate it. That's all..

Comment: Ok, I'll edit my question

Comment: don't wrap just edit the generated `tabular` and replace it by `longtable` keeping the body of the table the same

Comment: do you mean replacing \afterpage{
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtabu}{X}
\begin{tabularx}{0.5\textheight}{X|l}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|} with \begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|} ?

Comment: well just `\begin{landscape}\begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|} `  would be a good start

Comment: it doesn't rotate.. =/

Comment: well you did something wrong then. As noted above you need to provide a complete self contained document that shows the problem

Comment: I've edited my question, it's complete now

Comment: Sorry it's not even close to complete `\input{Capa}` and it includes many unrelated packages but it's probably enough to attempt an answer

Answer (score 3):

This isn't quite right but will get you started, please in future make a complete single document, as here. Note there were many errors in the use of `|` in `\multicolumn`, you should only put rules on the right, except for the first column. Also you need to not use `l` columns as they don't allow the cell contents to wrap.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,openany]{book}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable,multirow}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Descrição do estudo de caso}
\label{descricao}


\begin{landscape}\tiny
\begin{longtable}{|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{2cm}{\centering\textbf{Atividade de Suporte}} & 
\multirow{2}{2cm}{\centering\textbf{Ligação com a cadeia de fornecedores (insumos)}}&
\centering\textbf{Atividades Primárias} &
\multirow{2}{5cm}{\centering\textbf{Ligação com a cadeia de distribuidores}}\\ \cline{3-7}
                                                                    &                                                                                                & \centering\textbf{Logística Interna} & \centering\textbf{Operações}& \centering \textbf{Logística Externa} & \centering \textbf{Marketing e Vendas} &
 \centering\textbf{Serviços}   &                                                                                        \\ \hline
\textbf{Aquisição}                                                  & Dados das Agências de Saúde                                                                    & \ttfamily\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}<span style="line-height: 1.5em;">Equipe</span>\\ <span style="line-height: 1.5em;">Hardware</span>\end{tabular} & Subentende-se a utilização de um software de gerenciamento do workflow & Não se aplica                                   & Não se aplica                                           & Realização de parcerias com Agências Internacionais de Saúde                               & Não se aplica                                                                          \\ \hline
\textbf{Tecnologia e Desenvolvimento}                               & Agrega valor com os dados fornecidos das empresas parceiras                                    & Transferência de tecnologia agregando valor ao conhecimento                                                                                 & Não se aplica                                                          & Não se aplica, pois o produto próprio           & Não se aplica, pois o projeto está no inicio            & Melhorar o algoritmo para dar mais precisão as previsões                                   & Permitir um acesso mais rápido a informação sobre as previsões                         \\ \hline
\textbf{Administração de Recursos Humanos}                          & Estabelecer parcerias com agências de saúde                                                    & Recrutamento de profissionais qualificados                                                                                                  & Manter atualização constante de treinamento especializado              & Não se aplica                                   & Não se aplica                                           & Tornar transparente as formas de acesso dos clientes à empresa para a correção do problema & Não se aplica                                                                          \\ \hline
\textbf{Sistemas de Administração}                                  & Garantir a privacidade dos usuários                                                            & Controle dos dados fornecidos pelas Agências de Saúde                                                                                       & Acompanhamento dos dados atualizados sobre gripe no mundo              & Não se aplica                                   & Acompanhamento de notícias relacionadas ao produto para & Apresentação dos resuldados através do site próprio                                        & Não se aplica                                                                          \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}



\end{document}
```

Comment: It doesn't work.. This is what I get: http://tinypic.com/r/1jmh48/5

Comment: @LuizFernando Are you using pdflatex?, what viewer was that? The code above produces the image above with pdflatex.

Comment: i'm using texmaker

Comment: @LuizFernando texmaker is an editor, it must be using some version of Tex in the background. What does your `.log` file say at the top?

Comment: Ohh I see. "This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012) (format=pdflatex 2012.10.29) "

Comment: @LuizFernando That image is _not_ produced from the code above (it shows page 18) start from the answer as given. If some other part of your code is breaking it, just add it back bit by bit until you find out what is to blame.

Comment: You are right. It actually works, although it doesn't rotate the table by 90 degrees as I was trying to accomplish with \begin{landscape}.

Comment: @LuizFernando yes, it does, look at the image I posted: the table text is rotated 90 degrees to the page head.